# How to create a cron like job using HangFire at startup?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have a service class that has a method like

```
public void BackgroundJob(string cronrule)
{
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("somejob", () => FetchCallHistoryAsync(), cronrule);
}
```

I want to put start the job in the startup, something like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    new MyClass().BackgroundJob("10 * * * *")
}
```

But my class depends on several other services, I don't know how to instantiate it from Startup.cs, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found a way

For any cases that you need to instantiate a service at startup, you register it at `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` and then inject it in `Configure(YourService yserv)`

For my special case I created a `CrontabService`

```cs
namespace MyApp
{
    public class CrontabService
    {
        private DependentService D;
        public CrontabService(DependentService d)
        {
              D = d
        }

        public Start()
        {
              RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("some-id", () => D.Job(), "*/15 * * * *");
        }
    }
}
```

This way all my crontab jobs stay on the same service.

Then I start it at `Startup.cs::Configure`

```cs
// Startup.cs
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         ...
         services.AddSingleton<DepedentService>();
         services.AddSingleton<CrontabService>();
      }
...
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CrontabService cron)
     {
          ...
          cron.Start();
          ...
     }
...
```

Comment: Just here to say your question and research has helped this lowly coder

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad that it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

For asp.net core 6 and above:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#resolve-a-service-at-app-start-up

```
    var app = builder.Build();

    using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

        var jobService = services.GetRequiredService<IJobsService>();

        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Shred Old Records", () => jobService.AutoShredOldReports(), Cron.Weekly);
    }
```